# Generation of six Random numbers related by a constraint

Tags: random

I want to generate six Random numbers $a,b,c,d,e,f$ (all are real and positive). They are related by $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2+e^2=1$ and $f$ is between 0 and 3. How can I generate those numbers?

Comment: `Append[Normalize[RandomReal[1, 5]], RandomReal[3]]`?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: @J.M. your suggestion is not working.

Comment: What version of *Mathematica* are you using?

Comment: I am using Mathematica 9

Comment: Both `Normalize[]` and `RandomReal[]` are already in version 9. Can you give details on why my (now edited) suggestion does not work?

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to write positive. I did some mistakes. It's working fine. Thanks @J.M.

Answer (score 3):

Letting the 5-vector $ x = \{a^2, b^2, c^2, d^2, e^2 \} = \{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5\}$ have `DirichletDistribution[{1,1,1,1,1}]`, `RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[{1,1,1,1,1}]]` gives a random 4-vector that satisfies $ 0 \leq x_i \leq 1$ and $\sum_{i=1}^4 x_i <1$. The 5th component of $x$ is determined by the condition $x_5= 1 - x_1 - x_2 - x_3 - x_4$. So appending $1 - \sum_{i=1}^4 x_i$ to $\{x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4\}$ returned by `RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[{1,1,1,1,1}]]` and taking `Sqrt`  we get a random vector $\{a, b, c, d, e \}$ that satisfies the condition.

Combining the steps in a function:

```
ClearAll[rvF]
rvF[dim_Integer, ss_: 1] := Sqrt[Append[#, 1 - Total[#]] & /@ 
    RandomVariate[DirichletDistribution[ConstantArray[1, dim]], ss]];
```

Examples:

```
rvF[5]
```

> {{0.866565, 0.266605, 0.134535, 0.307307, 0.255831}}

```
rvF[5,10]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

To get a sample of size 10 for the 6-vector,  $\{a, b, c, d, e , f \}$  with `f` distributed uniformly on `[0,3]`:

```
Join @@@ Transpose[{rvF[5, 10], List /@ RandomReal[3, {10}]}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Further examples:

```
cp = ContourPlot3D[ x^2 + y^2 + z^2 == 1, {x, 0, 1}, {y, 0, 1}, {z, 0, 1},
   Mesh -> None, ContourStyle -> Directive[Yellow, Opacity[0.7]]];
Show[cp, ListPointPlot3D[rvF[3, 1000]]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 2):

To settle this: `Append[Normalize[RandomReal[1, 5]], RandomReal[3]]` produces a set of numbers that satisfies the OP's request. What distribution this tuple follows is a different kettle of fish.

Comment: If I am reading OP correctly @bob, he only wants the first 5 to satisfy the normalization condition, and the sixth to be within $(0,3)$. `Normalize[]` will map the sixth number back to $(0,1)$.

Comment: If we want to sample uniformly from the set of all tuples that satisfy the constraint, we could do `Normalize /@ Select[RandomReal[1, {100, 5}], 0.1 < Norm[#] < 1 &]`.  The upper bound on the norm ensures (five-dimensional) spherical symmetry.  The lower bound avoids numerical instability when `Normalize`ing.  This has to be repeated until a sufficient number of tuples are generated.  Since this is rejection sampling, we don't know in advance how many will pass the test.

Comment: @Szabolcs, yes, one alternative would be to use something like a `While[]` loop to return the first admissible tuple from the rejection sampling.